# Makefile looks at environment variables set in sub-makefile even though I'm not calling that one

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I am wanting to build 2 variants of the same software using one makefile. The code knows which one to build by looking at an environment variable VARIANT. I know environment variables can't be set within recipes so I thought I'd try calling a different sub-Makefile depending on the variant.

These are my makefiles:

Makefile:

```
all: variant1 variant2

variant1:
include Makefile.variant1

variant2:
include Makefile.variant2
```

Makefile.variant1:

```
VARIANT := variant1

publishv1: [rest of recipe]
```

Makefile.variant2:

```
VARIANT := variant2

publishv2: [rest of recipe]
```

What's inside [rest of recipe] is essentially the same for both, except the code picks up the VARIANT and it differs based on that.

The trouble is, if I try

> make variant1 publishv1

or just

> make publishv1

it is still picking up the VARIANT from Makefile.variant2. If I comment out the environment variable in Makefile.variant2, it builds variant 1.

Is there any other way I can do this with the makefiles?

**EDIT**

So this is what I'm doing at the moment, and it works:

Makefile.var1

```
export VARIANT=var1
include Makefile.common
```

Makefile.var2

```
export VARIANT=var2
include Makefile.common
```

Makefile.common

```
publish: [python files that use VARIANT]
```

So to make either variant, I run

> make -f Makefile.varX publish

What I'd like to do is be able to build either one, or both, from one makefile.
From your suggestions I have tried this, which doesn't work:

```
export VARIANT

variant1: VARIANT:=variant1
variant1: publish

variant2: VARIANT:=variant2
variant2: publish

publish: [python files that use VARIANT]
```

Is there a way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

First, these are not *environment* variables.  They're *make* variables (or make macros).

Second, I'm not sure what magic you're attributing to the `include` operation but all this does is import the content of the file exactly as if you'd typed it into the first makefile.  So in your case it would be as if you wrote your makefile like this:

```
all: variant1 variant2

variant1:
VARIANT := variant1

publishv1: [rest of recipe]

variant2:
VARIANT := variant2

publishv2: [rest of recipe]
```

It's not like sticking an `include` after a target like `variant1`, will somehow make that include only be invoked if that target is run, or something like that.

Third, you should move away from the idea that you're "calling" a target; makefiles are not procedural languages and targets are not functions that are called.

The way you can do this depends entirely on what you want to *do* with the `VARIANT` variable: how it is used.  You haven't shown us anything related to that.

If you just want to use it within a recipe, then you can use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) to handle this:

```
all: variant1 variant2

export VARIANT

variant1: VARIANT := variant1
variant1: publish

variant2: VARIANT := variant2
variant2: publish

publish:
        [rest of recipe using $(VARIANT)]
```

**ETA**

OK, so your comments say you want this `make` variable to be provided into the environment of commands make invokes.  That's simple enough, you just need to export it from your makefile; add:

```
export VARIANT
```

Comment: The variable is used by python files on building the SW. The python files can't access the variable using the way you've suggested. At the moment I'm using two different makefiles like this:
`export VARIANT=variantX`
`publish: [rest of recipe]`
and in cmd I run
> make -f makefile.variant1 publish
I'd like to build either variant from the same makefile instead of 2 separate makefiles.

Comment: Exporting the variable works if I have separate makefiles, but I want to be able to build them both in the same makefile. It's not possible to export a variable from within a recipe, from what I have read and tried, it has to be set at the beginning of the makefile. So how can I set the value of this variable depending on what I want to build?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  A make variable is either exported, or not exported.  It's a binary; it's not just exported for some targets and not for others.  Just add the export line, like I showed.  It should be outside of any recipe, all by itself, not indented with TAB, somewhere in the makefile.  I will edit my example.

Comment: If I export the variable outside of the recipes, and then try to set the value within the recipes, the value is then not visible to the python files that uses it. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: That is not true (that the value is not visible).  When you run `make variant1` then `VARIANT` will be exported and set to `variant1`.  When you run `make variant2` then it will be exported and set to `variant2`.  I have run this experiment and it works.  Please clarify what you mean when you say "doesn't work" and explain what result you saw and why it wasn't correct.  As an experiment you can modify your recipe to just run `echo $$VARIANT` which will print the value of the `VARIANT` environment variable so you can see what it is set to.